# XML documentation for interface methods and record properties

Tags: f#, intellisense, c#-to-f#

It seems the XML documentation works fine for the most cases, but not always. I wanted to make the Intellisense fully available for the parts that are designed for interoperating with C#. So, here's a small (and maybe a bit contrived) example:

```
///<summary>Well, it's a summary</summary>
type Summary = {
    ///<summary>Gets a short name</summary>
    Name : string;

    ///<summary>Gets whether the action was successful or not</summary>
    IsSuccessful : bool;
}

///<summary>Represents path filtering action</summary>
type IPathFilter =
    ///<summary>Runs the filtering through the list of <paramref name="paths"/></summary>
    ///<param name="paths">A sequence of paths to check</param>
    ///<returns>A sequence of <see cref="Summary"/></returns>
    abstract member Run : seq<string> -> seq<Summary>

///<summary>A default filter</summary>
type PathFilter =
    
    ///<summary>Runs the filtering through the list of <paramref name="paths"/></summary>
    ///<param name="paths">A sequence of paths to check</param>
    ///<returns>A sequence of <see cref="Summary"/></returns>
    member this.Run paths=
        paths |> Seq.map (fun s -> FileInfo(s)) |> Seq.map (fun f -> { Name = f.Name; IsSuccessful = f.Exists; })

    interface IPathFilter with
        ///<summary>Runs the filtering through the list of <paramref name="paths"/></summary>
        ///<param name="paths">A sequence of paths to check</param>
        ///<returns>A sequence of <see cref="Summary"/></returns>
        member this.Run paths = 
            this.Run paths
```

The class and the interface are there only for C# interop, a facade for all the magic stuff that happens inside F# library, so I don't have to expose the F# specific stuff to C#. It would be nice to have full docs available on C# side, which brings me to my two questions:

1. Is there a way to have the record properties documented and visible in Intellisense? If I hover over the type itself everything works, but properties don't seem to be picked up:
   [image: Record 'class' documentation]
   [image]
2. Is there a way to have a 'full' description for abstract methods? I know, from F# side they're only described as a function signature. Unfortunately, that means if I'm using the interface, I'll get incomplete docs on the method; the parameter names and descriptions will be missing:

   [image: Interface method doc]

   Compared to the raw class documentation:
   [image: Class method doc]

Is there anything I can do, or should I just learn to live with it? :)

---

### [EDIT]

As noted by Gustavo, record docs seem to work just fine on F# side (checked using VS2012 Professional):

[image: FSharp record doc]

Unfortunately same docs are *not* visible in C#:

[image: FSharp record doc in CSharp]

:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you can omit the `summary` tag when you don't have other tags like `params` and `returns`. So this:

```
///Well, it's a summary
type Summary
```

is equivalent to this:

```
///<summary>Well, it's a summary</summary>
type Summary
```

1) Descriptions for record fields work in VS2012:

[image]

2) You can use parameter names in abstract methods like this:

```
type IPathFilter =
    abstract member Run : paths:seq<string> -> seq<Summary>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint in point 2. Pity it's not possible that record fields can't be documented, those are get-only properties after all... I knew about the `///` shorthand, but it doesn't work at all with `<paramref>` and `<cref>`, so most of the time I have a habit of using the full `<summary>` version and `///` only when it's plain text without cross-references. Thanks for clearing things up!

Comment: Actually, I retested this, and record fields do work in VS2012

Comment: Oh, OK, I was using VS2013, I don't know if it makes any difference. I'll also check if the record docs are visible from C#...

Comment: Yes, I don't have access to VS2013 right now, but I think I tested the first time with VS2013. Maybe it's a bug introduced in VS2013. Let us know

Comment: Yup, checked it. Your version checks out, the docs are visible in F#, but not so much in C#... No idea why :(

Comment: That's weird, in C# record fields are seen as simple read-only properties, so the documentation should be mantained. Maybe it's worth sending a bugreport to fsbugs@microsoft.com?

Comment: After getting a reply from Microsoft it turns out it is indeed a bug, the team responsible can reproduce it and they will follow up on it. :)

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Patryk Ćwiek in the comment above, Microsoft has confirmed this as a bug. Just to clarify what actually happens: When the F# compiler generates the documentation file, it actually documents the *internal field* instead of the *public property* of the record member.

For instance, the documentation for your `Summary` type above is generated as:

```
...
<member name="F:Test.Summary.IsSuccessful">
   <summary>Gets whether the action was successful or not</summary>
</member>
<member name="F:Test.Summary.Name">
   <summary>Gets a short name</summary>
</member>
<member name="T:Test.Summary">
   <summary>Well, it's a summary</summary>
</member>
...
```

Note the `F:` prefix in the documentation of the member names. Change that to `P:` and Visual Studio immediately displays the comments in your C# project. So until this bug is fixed and the documentation is actually generated for the properties, the only option you have is to manually process the documentation file in a post-build step.

By the way, this also explains why it works in F#: Apparently, the F# bindings for Visual Studio use the field to look up the documentation. This even works across several F# libraries, despite the fact that the field has internal visibility.

Update: This bug should be fixed with F# 3.1.2. See also [the release notes](https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#changelist.txt).