# Incorrect IntelliSense XML generated for F# record values (VS2013)

Tags: xml, f#, visual-studio-2013, intellisense, record

**Update:** as noted in the comments, this is a bug. I've [reported it to Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/816006/incorrect-intellisense-xml-generated-for-f-record-values) and it has been routed to a VS development team for investigation. I'll update this answer if and when there's news.

**Further update:** a fix has been [committed to the project on CodePlex](https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/2d8ebcd43baaa8d09647eb46426a0396e6b73799), yay!

---

Given a record type:

```ml
namespace Rather.Deep.Namespace

type TestRecord = {
    /// Property summary
    Prop : string
}
```

VS2013 generates the following IntelliSense XML for this field:

```xml
<member name="F:Rather.Deep.Namespace.Rather.Deep.Namespace.TestRecord.Prop">
 <summary>Property summary</summary>
</member>
```

I know about record values being [treated as though they are fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21302280/230390) and not properties. I can deal with that. What I can't understand is: **why is the namespace being doubled?**

(If you want to try for a repro, create a new library project in VS2013 containing nothing but that file, and look at the generated XML file in the `bin` folder. I just updated to VS2013.1—still no dice.)

Comment: My guess is that this is indeed a bug.  I would report it on connect http://connect.microsoft.com/

Comment: @JaredPar That's my guess too, but I wanted to see if anyone has an obscure explanation for what might be going on. (Or, indeed, a reference to an existing bug!) If I don't get any answers by tomorrow I'll report it. :)

Comment: This, indeed, looks like a bug. This, indeed, looks like a bug.

Comment: @TomasPetricek I concur. I concur. :) Couldn't find an existing issue on Connect, so I [reported it myself](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/816006/incorrect-intellisense-xml-generated-for-f-record-values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, and a couple of commentators agreed, this is a bug. I submitted a [bug report on Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/816006/incorrect-intellisense-xml-generated-for-f-record-values) with a minimal test project attached, and not too long later **a fix was [committed to the project on CodePlex](https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/2d8ebcd43baaa8d09647eb46426a0396e6b73799)**. Good job, F# team!