# ASP.NET Web API Help Page generates incomplete documentation for F# record types

Tags: asp.net-web-api, f#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api-helppages

The ASP.NET Web API Help Page project does not produce complete documentation for F# record types used as parameters or result types for Web API controller actions. Members are listed, but summary information in XML comments is not displayed in the generated documentation. How do I fix this?

## Example

Consider the following F# record type being used as a parameter or result type for a Web API action method:

```ml
[<CLIMutable>]
type ExampleRecord = {

    /// Example property.
    Prop : int
```

### Expected output

The generated help page documentation for this type should include the summary information in description column for this member.

```
Name  │ Description       │ Type    │ Additional information
══════╪═══════════════════╪═════════╪═══════════════════════
Prop  │ Example property. │ integer │ None.
```

### Actual output

What we actually see is that the summary information is completely absent.

```
Name  │ Description │ Type    │ Additional information
══════╪═════════════╪═════════╪═══════════════════════
Prop  │             │ integer │ None.
```

### Specifics

This issue occurs in relation to the following specific technologies:

- Microsoft ASP.NET Web API Help Pages v5.1.1;
- Visual Studio Professional 2013 (Update 1); and
- F# 3.1 compiler.

Despite the self-answer, the floor is wide open to better solutions as what I've got currently doesn't really cut mustard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** the [doubled namespace issue has been fixed](https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/2d8ebcd43baaa8d09647eb46426a0396e6b73799). Future readers may need to adjust the code below. Specifically, you might need to change `"${namespace}${namespace}${class}"` to `"${namespace}${class}"`. Don't say I didn't warn you!

---

The problem arises because of two bugs related to how XML documentation is generated for F# record types:

1. "When the F# compiler generates the documentation file, it actually documents the internal field instead of the public property of the record member."—[Axel Habermaier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21302280/230390)
2. The [namespace of a record member is doubled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21412083/230390) in the generated XML.

Barring an update to Visual Studio 2013 (or perhaps just the F# compiler), the best fix for this would probably be a post-build action that cleans up the generated XML. For now, I have a temporary fix that involves changing the method that gets the documentation for members.In `Areas/HelpPage/XmlDocumentationProvider`, find the method with the signature:

```cs
public string GetDocumentation(MemberInfo member)
```

…and replace the definition with:

```cs
public string GetDocumentation(MemberInfo member)
{
    string selectExpression;
    bool isRecord = FSharpType.IsRecord(member.DeclaringType, FSharpOption<BindingFlags>.None);

    if (isRecord)
    {
        // Workaround for a bug in VS 2013.1: duplicated namespace in documentation for record types.
        Regex matchTypeName = new Regex(@"(?<namespace>(?:[_\p{L}\p{Nl}]+\.)*)(?<class>[_\p{L}\p{Nl}]+)$");
        string classExpression = matchTypeName.Replace(GetTypeName(member.DeclaringType), "${namespace}${namespace}${class}");
        string memberExpression = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}.{1}", classExpression, member.Name);
        selectExpression = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, FieldExpression, memberExpression);
    }
    else
    {
        string expression = member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field ? FieldExpression : PropertyExpression;
        string memberName = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}.{1}", GetTypeName(member.DeclaringType), member.Name);
        selectExpression = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, expression, memberName);
    }

    XPathNavigator propertyNode = _documentNavigator.SelectSingleNode(selectExpression);
    return GetTagValue(propertyNode, "summary");
}
```

**This is a very temporary fix!** It will be overwritten if you update the Web API Help Pages package, and will break things if the aforementioned bugs are fixed. I'd really appreciate any help finding a better solution.